# Bulk update in mysql taking long time for 24000 records

Tags: mysql, bulkupdate

My requirement is to update the records in X table if records exists otherwise insert it.
To achieve this , I created temporary table and inserted all records in the temp table. later I ran update query on X table based on primary keys using inner join between X and temp table. For the new records, I ran insert query using where not exists condition. My insert query is completed in a minute for 24000 records but update query for 24000 records taking 13 minutes to complete.

is there a way to reduce time to update 24000 records in mysql?
update query which I used:

```
update x
  join x_temp 
    on x.primarykey = x_temp.primarykey 
   set X.col1 = x_temp.col1
     , x.col2 = x_temp.col2 ..
```

Comment: No. I think you're stuck unless you can add a WHERE clause of some kind

Comment: I added where condition with primary keys but still taking time

Comment: 13 minutes for 24000 rows is ridiculous. I would be tempted to try this on a different server to see if things improve.

Comment: I would like to mention here that we are using 7GB RAM.does increasing RAM will increase performance?